# How to use MATRIX_EVAL to enable a build matrix row based on a compiler?

Tags: c++, gcc, travis-ci, ubsan

Our Travis [build matrix](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/.travis.yml) includes a row that builds with Undefined Behavior sanitizer:

```
  matrix:
    - BUILD_MODE="all"
    - BUILD_MODE="no-asm"
    - BUILD_MODE="asan"
    - BUILD_MODE="ubsan"
```

GCC requires 4.9 (or maybe 5.0) for UBsan, and its causing our test to fail on Trusty:

```
...
$ gcc --version
gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
...

g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -fPIC -march=native -pipe -fsanitize=undefined -DCRYPTOPP_COVERAGE -c cryptlib.cpp
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-fsanitize=undefined’
make: *** [cryptlib.o] Error 1

The command "make "$BUILD_MODE" && ./cryptest.exe v && ./cryptest.exe tv all" exited with 2.
```

Travis has something called `MATRIX_EVAL` which looks like some sort of selector. I think it can be used to enable or disable a row in the build matrix, but its not clear to me how to use it. The documentation is at [add documentation for upgrading gcc and clang](https://github.com/travis-ci/docs-travis-ci-com/pull/746/files/0715103e3f0ee732ad66b51911150bcb76bccee1), but its not explained well. Also see [Building a C Project](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/languages/c/) in the Travis docs.

How do we use `MATRIX_EVAL` to enable the UBsan row when GCC is 4.9 or greater? Or maybe, if `MATRIX_EVAL` is the wrong tool, then how do we tell Travis to enable the build when GCC is 4.9 or higher?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, this is awkward. I'm the one who wrote that PR into the docs - stumbled across this because of a comment on the merged PR.

`MATRIX_EVAL` in this context is simply an environment variable - notice that it is specified in the `env` of every `matrix.include`. In the context of the [linked documentation](https://github.com/sxlijin/docs-travis-ci-com/blob/1951c90442f5f475270c7cf150ab989500d8a534/user/languages/_includes/c11-cpp11-and-beyond-and-toolchains.md), the `before_install` step common to every build matrix entry just runs `eval "${MATRIX_EVAL}"`.

In other words, `MATRIX_EVAL` is nothing special. It's just one way of defining conditional behavior in a Travis build matrix entry. From the `.travis.yml` file you linked, the solution would just be adding a shell script conditional on `BUILD_MODE` in the `script` step.

Comment: Thanks @Pockets. When you say, *"... adding a shell script conditional on BUILD_MODE in the script step"*, do you mean something like `MATRIX_EVAL("$BUILD_MODE"="X" && "$GCC_VERSION" -ge "4.9")`? If not, then could you show me what you mean? Sorry to ask. I have very little Travis skills, so I often struggle with simple tasks.

Comment: "shell script conditional" just means to write a conditional in the shell script, i.e. in your script step, do something like `if [[ "$BUILD_MODE" = ubsan && "$GCC_VERSION" -lt 4.9 ]]; then :; else make && ./run_binary; fi`. You could also use `case` for switch statement-like behavior. Note that `GCC_VERSION` is not set by default, so you'll have to write that test yourself somehow (also that version numbers can't be interpreted as floats).